# can I use k-means in rapidminer?

Tags: k-means, rapidminer

can I use k-means in rapidminer to cluster 8000 text file that contains tags of 8000 image? and if it's possible what is the suitable K and max runs should be chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a k-Means Operator in RapidMiner, even some additional variations like k-Means with kernels and X-means.
To process the text file you can use the Text Processing extension, available at the RapidMiner marketplace.

The best parameter settings depend of course on your data, but you try out different settings. One way would be to put the k-means Operator inside an "Optimize Parameter", the performance can be evaluated with one of the cluster performance Operators or by a self defined performance measure.

Comment: thank you for helping... Can I use any operator to remain English word only and remove any word in any other language???

Comment: I haven't done this myself so far. Could be tricky because after stemming the words might be similar.  You could try the [Aylien Text Analysis Extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_com.aylien.textapi.rapidminer) from the RapidMiner Marketplace, it features a language detection support-